# Attribution - Facebook dynamic ads. What really resulted in purchases

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, e-commerce, google-tag-manager, facebook-ads-api

I have a dynamic Facebook campaign running. I would like to know exactly how many purchases that came from Facebook traffic on my dynamic remarketing campaign. A retargeting campaign is obviously remarketing to all website traffic and with this, a lot of the purchases I see in FB is obviously also from organic as well ad AdWords etc.

My question is: How can I know how many purchases from my Facebook dynamic remarketing campaign that actually came from Facebook, to begin with.

Comment: Please can you post an example of the code you've tried and the results you got?

Answer (score -1):

Look in the Multi-channel and Attribution reports. You don't have to use these with any of the default channel groupings, you can use "Campaign" as your first dimension. However, be aware that GA does not have cross-device tracking.

Facebook's own conversion tracking will tell you if any of the campaign resulted in a conversion when it was not the first click, and will track across across devices, as they match Facebook account information.